# TCP/IP Socket-Server Concurrent

Tags: sockets, unix, concurrency, tcp

I want to make a social network using a server and a client in Unix C. I know how to develop some minimalistic things about this architecture, but I want to make the server concurrent. What do you guys suggest me? Of course, not an iterative model ; I'm not going to use fork neither, because the server should accept clients, read from the clients and write to the clients. What about some threading methods or multiplexing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to start with multiplexing.

Take a look at these functions

- select http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/select.2.html
- epoll http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html

You can build your server around the reactor pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern